# Django admin runs query multiple times

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-debug-toolbar

I have a function defined in `list_items` in django admin as follows:

```
def won(self):
    result = (Result.objects.filter(user=self)
              .select_related('user')
              .aggregate(Sum('prize'))['prize__sum'])
    return result if result else 0
```

A result contains a foreign key to user, as well as a 'prize', defining the amount of points a user earned.

Using Django Debug Toolbar, I've discovered that each user being listed results in 40 identical queries being run to calculate the 'won' value for each user.

```
SELECT SUM("games_result"."prize") AS "prize__sum" FROM "games_result" WHERE "games_result"."user_id" = 28297
Duplicated 40 times.
```

Am I doing something really obviously wrong to cause this problem? Is there a better way of getting the Result objects with a link to this user?

Answer (score 3):

Considering your user has a field named `results`, which represents all of the results from the games for a certain user you can use [annotate aggregation function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/) to add a field to each user and then on every user you can simpy select the prize_sum as in this example:

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('won', )

    def won(self):
        return self.prize_sum

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return super(UserAdmin, self).get_queryset(
            request).select_related('results').annotate(prize_sum=Sum('results__prize'))
```

Comment: Does this still work if results isn't a field, but is a table consisting of results for all users? Its basically a table that stores the user, and their prize.